# Android market listed names

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

In the android market, which part of the androidmanifest.xml determines the app's name and dev name that is shown to public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dev Name** is linked to your developper account.

[image]

**App's name in the Market**= What you wrote in your developper console.

[image]

**App's name in the device**= What you wrote in your Manifest.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```